# how can I use Selenium with ChromeDriver to automate google with a defined profile?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
  Sub envArquivo()

  Dim minhaPagina   As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
  
  Dim keys  As New Selenium.keys
  
  Dim contato, arquivo, msg As String
  
  Planilha1.Select
  
  contato = Range("c2").Value
  arquivo = Range("c3").Value
  msg = Range("c4").Value
  
  Url = "https://web.whatsapp.com/"
  
  minhaPagina.Start
  minhaPagina.Get Url
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))  

End Sub
```

I tried in several ways to assign the opening of chrome to my already configured profile or try to configure a profile and leave it saved, but I was unsuccessful!

I hope there is a way to configure a fixed profile to facilitate the sending of WhatsApp web files, or would it be possible to use an API for integration with VBA?